# Error compiling a pixel shader

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sharpdx

I am trying to compile a pixel shader to be used in SharpDX - more specifically, as an Effect (to apply to an image).

I am compiling it using their tkfxc compiler.

The shader code is:

```
float4 test(float4 pos: SV_POSITION) : SV_TARGET{
return float4(1,0,0,1);
}

technique named{

    pass p0{

        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_3 test();

    }

}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error: [image]

Anybody experienced this error before? I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.